# Как получить данные из массива?

Tags: массивы, php

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[8]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Экспорт' (length=14)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 0
      public 'operationAttribute' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 0
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Германия DEFRAA' (length=23)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-09-08T09:50:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[3]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Импорт' (length=12)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 9
      public 'operationAttribute' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 0
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '130980' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Москва EMS ММПО' (length=25)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-08T11:33:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0.238
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '394880' (length=6)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string 'Воронеж, Воронежская обл.' (length=46)
  2 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[7]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Приём на таможню' (length=30)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 11
      public 'operationAttribute' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 0
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '130980' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Москва EMS ММПО' (length=25)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-09T05:00:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0.238
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  3 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[5]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Таможенное оформление' (length=41)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 14
      public 'operationAttribute' => string 'Выпуск таможни' (length=27)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 1
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '130980' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Москва EMS ММПО' (length=25)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-09T05:11:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0.238
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  4 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[10]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Обработка' (length=18)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 8
      public 'operationAttribute' => string 'Покинуло место международного обмена' (length=69)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 6
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '130980' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Москва EMS ММПО' (length=25)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-09T23:57:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  5 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[6]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Обработка' (length=18)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 8
      public 'operationAttribute' => string 'Сортировка' (length=20)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 0
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '130100' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Москва EMS СЦ' (length=21)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-10T23:47:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  6 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[11]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Обработка' (length=18)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 8
      public 'operationAttribute' => string 'Покинуло сортировочный центр' (length=54)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 4
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '130100' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Москва EMS СЦ' (length=21)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-11T15:42:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  7 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[12]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Обработка' (length=18)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 8
      public 'operationAttribute' => string 'Сортировка' (length=20)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 0
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '394880' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Воронеж EMS СЦ' (length=23)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-12T07:58:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  8 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[13]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Обработка' (length=18)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 8
      public 'operationAttribute' => string 'Прибыло в место вручения' (length=45)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 2
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '394880' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Воронеж EMS СЦ' (length=23)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-12T09:37:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
  9 => 
    object(RussianPostTrackingRecord)[14]
      public 'operationType' => string 'Вручение' (length=16)
      public 'operationTypeId' => int 2
      public 'operationAttribute' => string 'Вручение адресату' (length=33)
      public 'operationAttributeId' => int 1
      public 'operationPlacePostalCode' => string '394880' (length=6)
      public 'operationPlaceName' => string 'Воронеж EMS СЦ' (length=23)
      public 'operationDate' => string '2012-10-12T14:10:00.000+04:00' (length=29)
      public 'itemWeight' => float 0.22
      public 'declaredValue' => float 0
      public 'collectOnDeliveryPrice' => float 0
      public 'destinationPostalCode' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'destinationAddress' => string '' (length=0)
```

Как из этого массива получить 1=>operationPlaceName?

Comment: @mountpoint, спасибо, переконвертируйте в ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загоняете этот массив в какую-то переменную, например, $array, и используете, например, так:

> > echo $array[1]->operationPlaceName